Efficiently Summing Values by Group in Julia similar to MATLAB's accumarray
I am translating some code from MATLAB to Julia. For context, I am relatively new to Julia and relatively seasoned in MATLAB. I have been struggling with the following specific operation that I do multiple times in my code. I need to sum the values of a variable by some pre-fixed ids. To make it very concrete think of the following operation:
│ ids   │ values │                      │ ids   | sum_values |
┼───────┼────────┤                      ┼───────┼────────────┤
│ 2     │ 1948.6 │      converted       │ 1     │ 3995.4     │
│ 1     │ 1994.7 │          to          │ 2     │ 1948.6     │
│ 3     │ 1940.1 │       ======>        │ 3     │ 3844.4     │
│ 1     │ 2000.7 │                      │ 4     │ 1982.0     │
│ 4     │ 1982.0 │                      
│ 3     │ 1904.3 │                      

But in reality think of these two as large arrays, ids and values (in Julia speak, they are Int64 and Float64). Each of these two arrays in my case have about 4 million observations. Note that ids is not necessarily sorted.
In MATLAB code, they look like the following:
rng(9491)

n_obs = 4*10^6; # number of observations
n_ids = 3*10^5; # number of unique ids

values = rand(n_obs,1);
ids = randsample(n_ids, n_obs,'true');

and in Julia:
using Random, StatsBase

Random.seed!(9491)

n_obs = 4*10^6  # number of observations
n_ids = 3*10^5  # number of unique ids

values = rand(n_obs);
ids = sample(1:n_ids, n_obs, replace=true);

So ids groups observations while values are just some values computed in an algorithm. In MATLAB, what I do to compute sum_values is simply to use:
sum_values = accumarray(ids,values);

and I have been having a hard time figuring out what is an extremely time efficient implementation of the same operation. For context, I do about 200,000 calls of the function in different ways (that is, with around 20 different ids, and thousands of different values) in my optimization routine.
I stumbled upon this 7-year old answer to a similar question that uses DataFrames but I don't know if this would fly in my setting where the key is to do it fast and then use the sum_values in other matrix operations. Note that these are large arrays, so putting them in a DataFrame, then using groupby then taking the values out, converting them into a Vector{Float64} may actually not be a great idea computationally (happy to be proven wrong). Using dictionaries sounded like a good idea but then it involves sorting (for some reason by dictionaries end up not sorted in ids).
What is the most efficient way to sum values by group in Julia? Any advice on how to implement this, or something similar, would be greatly appreciated.

Have you tried implementing and comparing the performance of the solutions in that answer? Can you share the code that you tried? What do benchmarks of your code show, and how does that compare to what you expect? How do those benchmarks compare to the MATLAB solution?

The optimal answer probably depends on whether you expect most groups to have any associated values. If there are values in most of the groups, then making an output vector is probably best, but if few groups have any values, then you can consider something like a Dict.
Anyway, here's a solution assuming a high 'fill grade'.
# provide an output vector, out, to write into. If you already know how long out should be beforehand, you can use that

function accumarray!(out, ids, val)
    for i in eachindex(ids, val)
        out[ids[i]] += val[i]
    end
    return out
end

# Calculate length of output vector, pre-allocate and call
accumarray(ids, val) = accumarray!(zeros(eltype(val), maximum(ids)), ids, val)

This should be pretty efficient, but it's not completely trivial to parallelize.

Thank you. What I am struggling with based on this solution is how does this create an array of the sum_values in ascending order of the ids, as accumarray would do. Like, I have run the code and it does, but I don't know why. Could you elaborate slightly as to why?

To follow up, this solution is crazy fast. The MATLAB takes about 0.01 seconds on this example, while this Julia one takes 0.006 seconds.

In Matlab, you could replace accumarray by sparse, using the
feature that values with the same indices are automatically added. So instead of
sum_values = accumarray(ids, values);

you could use
sum_values = full(sparse(ids, 1, values));

which is reasonably fast.
I don't know Julia, but based on the documentation it has the same behaviour for sparse arrays (and lets you choose the combining function). So you could use
sum_values = Array(sparse(ids, ones(Int,length(ids)), values));

I don't know how fast that will be.

Thanks for tip on MATLAB. For reference, accumarray based on the example above takes ~0.01 seconds while full(sparse( )) takes ~0.1 seconds so it is an order of magnitude slower. I'll check with Julia to see if this would fly,

The short answer:
countmap(ids, values)

(it's defined in StatsBase which you already loaded)
This is quite efficient. For example:
julia> ids = rand(1:3, 5)
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 3
 3
 2
 3
 1

julia> values = rand(1:20,5)
5-element Vector{Int64}:
  8
 16
 11
  7
  6

julia> countmap(ids,values)
Dict{Int64, Int64} with 3 entries:
  2 => 11
  3 => 31
  1 => 6


Thank you. What I am struggling with based on this solution is how to recover an array of the sum_values in ascending order of the ids, as accumarray would do.

A Dict d with the values is usually more useful than an array, but if an array is needed, and the IDs are 1:3 then getindex.(Ref(d),1:3) will get it, or just to get the values of IDs in the dict:  collect(values(sort(d))). In any case, the Dict might be what you really need.

collect with sort is what I did, but this sorting makes the code inefficient.
And I wholeheartedly agree a dict may be what I need, I am just trying to figure out how to use it (if that makes sense). These calculated are then used as sum_values[id2] where id2 is a different vector that expands the sum_values into a different vector.

Try getindex.(Ref(d), id2) (note the extra . after getindex for broadcasting). This will expand d into an id2 sized array.
